# I'm searching for a USB-C (not USB-A) switch. But does such a device even exist?

Tags: displays, kvm, usb-c, docking-stations

**TL;DR :** I'm trying to find a way to share a USB-C connection with at least 2 sources, like a switch or a KVM. But I only found USB-A switches so far.

---

I'm struggling to find the appropriate hardware for my problem.

I have a triple display setup connected to my work laptop (and sometimes my own personnal computer) through a docking station ([D6000 from DELL](https://www.dell.com/en-uk/work/shop/dell-universal-dock-d6000/apd/452-bcyj/pc-accessories)).

But I'd like to avoid unplugging and plugging back the docking station to avoid as much cable management as I can. So I tried adding a USB-3 switch (USB-A, [this one](https://www.startech.com/en-us/cards-adapters/hbs304a24a)), but it look like going through USB-A makes triple display non-functionnal (1 of my monitors doesn't work that way, confirmed by the [manual](https://downloads.dell.com/manuals/all-products/esuprt_electronics_accessories/esuprt_electronics_accessories_pc_tablet/dell-universal-dock-d6000_user%27s-guide_en-us.pdf)).

So, I'm trying to find an equivalent, but full USB-C (Switching an USB-C stream through different sources, like pushing a button would change the selected USB-C source *but to an USB-C output*), yet so far I have found none.
I have searched on several websites (Startech constructor website, amazon, several search engines...), but so far I failed to find one.

Any hardware recommendation that would meet my requirements ?

Desired setup :

```
Monitor    Monitor    Monitor    Other peripherals
   |          |         |               |
   |----------|----|----|---------------|
                   |
                   |
                   |
         D6000 docking station (requires USB-C for functionnal triple display)
                   |
                   |   <=== Currently USB-A from the switch, I would like it to be USB-C (without having to use an adapter)
                   |
          |---- Switch ----|
          |                |
          |                |
       Laptop           Desktop
```

Comment: I have a feeling this question is already asked 4 times last year, but I can't say for sure...

Comment: web search `usb-c hub` or `usb-c kvm`